# ARKit 3.5 body tracking by LIDAR

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, lidar

As you definitely know iPad Pro has LIDAR to track 3D space around and it is capable to measure space around.

Does anyone have any experience or tip how to measure body parts using ARKit 3(using iPhone X ...) / 3.5 with LIDAR?

I checked documentation but there wasn't anything related to this problem.

Thank you all!